# Installation of net-snmp - How do I resolve the dependencies?

Tags: redhat, rpm, dependencies

I'm trying to install net-snmp on `Redhat 2.6.9-55.ELsmp` by following the [instructions](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/INSTALL.html).

The problem is I get this:

```
grep: /usr/lib/libbeecrypt.la: No such file or directory
/bin/sed: can't read /usr/lib/libbeecrypt.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `/usr/lib/libbeecrypt.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[1]: *** [libnetsnmpmibs.la] Error 1
```

On the net-snmp website there is a [page](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ:Compiling_03) that explains that I may need to install a dev version of the beecrypt library.

So, I find a link to [beecrypt-devel-4.1.2-10.1.1.el6.rf.i686.rpm](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/i386/dag/RPMS/beecrypt-devel-4.1.2-10.1.1.el6.rf.i686.rpm) and run:

```
rpm -ivh <path>\beecrypt-devel-4.1.2-10.1.1.el6.rf.i686.rpm
```

But that then comes up with a load of other missing dependencies. I found some info on the internet explaining that if I install rpmdb-redhat, then I can use the `--aid` option to automatically resolve the dependencies... but it doesn't seem to make the slightest bit of difference!

Am I missing something here? Do I really have to manually install each and every dependency? One of the dependencies is GLIBC_2.4, and I have no idea which .rpm file I need for my system.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep beecrypt`?

Comment: @quanta: `beecrypt-3.1.0-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install `beecrypt-devel` with corresponding version.

Comment: I'm trying... but there is loads of missing dependencies! Also, how do I know what version `net-snmp` needs?

Comment: Give us the output?

Comment: Sorry... ignore that comment... I just realised what you meant. It worked! Thanks for your help.